# creating dynami Array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to create array with row like this :

```
 dateMetric : [{date : DatNoDuplicate[i] , ClickCount : 0 , Retweet : 0 , LikeCount : 0 , ShareCount : 0, Tweet : 0, CommentCount: 0, SumMetric: 0}, 
           {date : DatNoDuplicate[i] , ClickCount : 0 , Retweet : 0 , LikeCount : 0 , ShareCount : 0, Tweet : 0, CommentCount: 0, SumMetric: 0}, 
          ]
```

but the attribute in rows( ClickCount, Retweet, LikeCount, ShareCount, Tweet, CommentCount) will be defined from other array,

Array nameMetric contains this name of rows(( ClickCount, Retweet, LikeCount, ...)

so if in nameMetric there is element (likeNumber, TweetNumber, .....) the array dateMetric will contain rows like this :

dateMetric

```
   date : DatNoDuplicate[i] , likeNumber: 0 , TweetNumber: 0 , ... , SumMetric: 0})
```

please help, i can reformulate the problem if it's not explained well .

Comment: please provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Show us more code, especially the `DatNoDuplicate` object

Comment: Mr Bergi, it's not interesting to provide DatNoDuplicate, Mr Greg has provided the right answers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/8cetN/

You can look up your name array to define the properties of each row object:

```
var nameMetric = ["ClickCount", "Retweet", "LikeCount", "ShareCount", "Tweet", "CommentCount", "SumMetric"];


var numRows = 4;
var dateMetric = [];

for (var i=0; i<numRows; i++) {

    var row ={};

    nameMetric.forEach(function(name){

        row[name] = 0; // Look up and place the actual value here.   


    });       

    dateMetric.push(row); 

}


console.log(JSON.stringify(dateMetric));
```